# Editing Local_Machine RegistryKeys Programmatically (C#)

Tags: c#, permissions, registry, admin

I'm trying to make a program that changes the registry key values on remote machines to block/allow users from personalizing their lock-screen images. It seems the key I need to create is at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization`with a name of `NoChangingLockScreen`.
I could easily do this with a .reg file and merge any changes into their registry (I planned on creating a windows service to monitor for changes in the file), although it seems I cannot even modify any keys inside the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` class. 
Please note:

- I am a domain admin across our network, and all remote computers have admin rights
- This issue does not just occur when modifying a remote PC's keys, but my own as well
- I've created the RegistryKey object as writable (See below code)
- It seems I cannot even use the OpenSubKey method, as reading the local_machine path just throws an object exception
- I've checked the permissions inside the Registry for that specific class and made sure my account had full control
- I have found very little documentation on other people having permissions issues

  ```
  RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows", true);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`Registry.ClassesRoot` is for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. You need to use `Registry.LocalMachine` field like this:

```
using (var registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows", writable: true))
{
    ...
}
```

Also note, that this is for **local** registry access. If you wish to open remote registry, you need to use another method:

```
using (var remoteBaseKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "RemoteMachineName"))
using (var registryKey = remoteBaseKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows", writable: true))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I combined two separate keys I had by accident, I did use `Registry.LocalMachine` in my test code and it still threw that exception when opening the SubKey

Comment: can you then add exact exception message and type to your question?

Comment: I don't have the project with me (It's on my PC at school) but I believe it was an 'object reference not set to an instance of an object' exception. I'll double check and verify in the morning.

Comment: @ZachRaudebaugh, oh, then it's a [NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) - the most frequent question on StackOverflow

Comment: Why would it return a NullReferenceException if I'm only opening the SubKey at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows` when that SubKey exists on all Windows machines? I could understand it returning the exception if I try to open a key I have not yet created, but I can't even open the existing key to modify anything.

Comment: well, we need to see your code, that throws an exception. For example, your code might be like this: `var myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(settings.BaseKey, true);` and at run time, `settings` object is `null`, so, accessing `BaseKey` property of `null` object will throw `NullReferenceException`

Comment: The line that is throwing the exception is `RegistryKey LockPersonalizeKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Personalization", true);` and the exception is `System.Security.SecurityException: 'Requested registry access is not allowed.'

Comment: 2 things to check: 1st - `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` right before `OpenSubKey` call, to make sure that you are authenticated as expected; 2nd - this may be UAC limitation. Can you try to run VisualStudio _as Administrator_?

Comment: 1) `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` returns my user account and IsAuthenticated as true 2} I changed app.manifest to always run this winForm app and VS as administrator